# Java8 enum avoid multiple if else

Tags: java, if-statement, enums, java-8

In java 8 is there any option to avoid multiple if else check with enum value and to  execute particular operation. I dont like to use  some thing like below example ?

```
if enum equals A 
 PRINT A
else if enum equals B
 PRINT B
else if enum equlas C
 PRINT C
```

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)?

Comment: You do not need to check the equality if the operation is always the same

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `switch` statements. And not just in Java 8, you can switch on `enums` in all previous versions of Java. Consider the following code:

```
public class Dummy {


    enum MyENUM {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MyENUM myENUM = MyENUM.A;
        switch (myENUM) {
            case A:
                System.out.println(MyENUM.A);
                break;
            case B:
                System.out.println(MyENUM.B);
                break;
            case C:
                System.out.println(MyENUM.C);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use `switch` statements, [This page](https://www.developer.com/java/data/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements.html) provides a various alternative to `switch` statements.

One of the ways to replace `switch` is to create a Map. Consider below example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Map<MyENUM,Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(MyENUM.A,() -> System.out.println(MyENUM.A));
    map.put(MyENUM.B,() -> System.out.println(MyENUM.B));
    map.put(MyENUM.C,() -> System.out.println(MyENUM.C));

    MyENUM myENUM = MyENUM.A;
    map.get(myENUM).run();
}
```

Produces following result:

```
A
```

Comment: Thanks.Can this be simplified without using switch statement in java8.. ?

Comment: @java_01 Updated the answer

Comment: You can replace the entire `switch` statement with `System.out.println(myEnum);`…

Comment: @Holger The purpose of OP's Question is NOT printing the enum. It's more of finding an alternative to `if-else`. Me, writing `System.out.println(MyENUM.A)` is basically showing some example of statement execution.

Comment: @PankajSinghal there is no indicator that the OP’s actual use case isn’t as superfluous as the given example which isn’t even valid Java syntax. Maybe the information that Java supports non-constant parameters which allow to avoid code duplication *is* valuable to the OP…

Comment: Based on the question & the OP's comment on the other answer, this is what I assumed. It could be something else also, as the OP hasn't accepted any answer, neither has expressed his opinion about any of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Define enum with abstract method and provide it's implementation with values.

```
enum MyEnum{
    A{
           @Override
           public void doSomething() {
             // Logic goes here
           }
        },
    B{
           @Override
           public void doSomething() {
             // Logic goes here
           }
        }

    abstract public void doSomething ();
}
```

Now, you can directly call the required method without an if.

```
MyEnum.B.doSomething();
```

Comment: A method receives a enum value and based on the enum value different actions will needs to be executed.So without if condition ,will the code snippet above can be implemented?

Comment: Yes, you just need to call doSomething method on the enum value inside the method which receives enum.

Comment: the receiver method needs an if else block. you are just shifting conditional block to receiver.